# Plotting (x^3 - x^2)^(1/3) gives unexpected results

Tags: plotting

I have a function

```
 g[x_] := (x^3 - x^2)^(1/3)
```

that I want to plot. The plot I am getting gives me strange results. There is nothing plotted for `x < 1`, contrary to the results that I can obtain from my calculator. Do you have a idea why?

Comment: You need to cut and paste both the code for the function and the code you used to `Plot` that failed to work properly. It might be related to the result creating an imaginary number.

Comment: The function is imaginary for certain values of x. You can see the real part of the solution by plotting `Plot[Re@g[x],{x,0,2}]` Also, I second Jack LaVinge.

Comment: Yes but i use mathematica exchange with my phone because i have issues with my connection at the moment. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: But as it is a ^(1/3) cubic roots normally the function is defined on R,isn t it?

Comment: For the origin of surd see [Etymology of "surd"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#Etymology_of_.22surd.22)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use [`Surd`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Surd.html) rather than [`Power`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power.html). *Mathematica* normally treats expressions as complex-valued, which may give results differing from most calculators, which are restricted to the reals. `Surd` is provided to give calculator-like behavior when that is desired.

```
g[x_] := Surd[x^3 - x^2, 3]
With[{a = 3}, Plot[g[x], {x, -a, a}]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Perfect thank you and do you know what is the origin of this label "Surd"?

Comment: @Bendesarts.  I believe it is an old word pertaining to the extraction of irrational roots of integers; recall that "absurd" and "irrational" are practically synonyms.

Comment: Or use `CubeRoot`.